# Get dates from weeks in month

Tags: php

i have a script which show all dates from weeks in month with new week start on Sunday.

How can i get week start on Monday?

thank you!

```
$month = 2;
$year = 2020;
$timestamp = mktime(0, 0 , 0, $month, 1, $year); 
$timestamp += (60 * 60 * 24); 
echo $first_week_no = date('W', $timestamp);
$range = range($first_week_no, $first_week_no + 4); 
foreach ($range as $week_no) {
    $week_start = new DateTime();
    $week_start->setISODate($year, $week_no);
    $week_start->modify('-1 day');

    $seven_day_week = array('sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday');
    $week = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
        $day = $seven_day_week[$i];
        $week[$day] = $week_start->format('Y-n-j');
        $week_start->modify('+1 day');
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    echo "Week {$week_no}";
    var_dump($week);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `N` format on the `$first_week_no = date('W', $timestamp);`

Try `$first_week_no = date('N', $timestamp);`

> Description: ISO-8601 numeric representation of the day of the week (added in PHP 5.1.0)
>
> Example returned values: 1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday)